# Why are my spaces registered as { }

Tags: python, tkinter

I made this simple program that translates from English to a completely different one (randomized English), when it displays the translation it shows spaces as { }. Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *

english = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
           'u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','!',
           '\"','#','$','%','&','\'','\'','(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/',':',';','?','@','[','\\',']','^','_','`','{','|','}','~',' ', ',','\t','\n','\r','\x0b','\x0c']

potatish =['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','v','l','d','e','z','j','s','i','x','q','u','f','b','o','y','c','m','t',
           'k','p','g','h','n','r','w','A','V','L','D','E','Z','J','S','I','X','Q','U','F','B','O','Y','C','M','T','K','P','G','H','N','R','W','!',
           '\"','#','$','%','&','\'','\'','(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/',':',';','?','@','[','\\',']','^','_','`','{','|','}','~',' ', ',','\t','\n','\r','\x0b','\x0c']


class Program(Frame):
    """ A Program to translate """

    def __init__ (self, master):
        """Initialise the frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Buttons!!!"""
        #Text
        self.text = Label(self, text = "Please enter some text:")
        self.text.grid()

        #Field
        self.user = Entry(self)
        self.user.grid()

        #Button
        self.translate = Button(self, text = "Translate")
        self.translate.grid()
        self.translate["command"] = self.update_console

        #Output
        self.output = Label(self, text = "Output:\n")
        self.output.grid()

        #finished
        self.finished = Label(self, text = "")
        self.finished.grid()

    def update_console(self):
        """Updates output"""
        self.trans = self.translatedef()
        self.finished["text"] = self.trans


    def translatedef(self):
        f = []
        i = -1
        j = -1
        text = self.user.get()
        while i != -2:
            i+=1
            try:
                l = english.index(text[i])
                f.append(potatish[l])
            except:
                while j != -2:
                    j+=1
                    try:
                        return f
                    except:
                        break
                break

root = Tk()
root.title("Potatish")
root.geometry("500x300")

app = Program(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `dict(zip(english, potatish))` to map input characters to output characters? It would be much more efficient than indexing `english` for every character, and you could use `whatever.get(char, char)` to avoid including the characters that should be unchanged in your lists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ive just used what i know how to use but im going to try and make the code more efficient and try and work out how to use the ones you have suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `text` of the Label to a list, not a string.  The empty element of that list is being displayed as `{}` by Tkinter.

To correct it, form a string from your list before you send it to the Label:

```
def update_console(self):
    """Updates output"""
    self.trans = ''.join(self.translatedef())
    self.finished["text"] = self.trans
```